# Removed Area still routed as an Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I tried adding an Area to my .Net Core MVC application, that didn't fit my needs so I removed it and replaced it with an controller with the same name (So same url). The problem is now that the application still treats it as an area (can see that because it redirects to azure ad for auth). I can't reach the controller, if I rename the controller, it works. I checked my pending changes for something that still points to areas, but I found nothing. Is something extra stored somewhere? I use IISExpress, already rebooted... No clue right now.

Comment: Can you please show us the RouteConfig.cs code and also Area registration in Global.asax.cs file. I think you need to change accordingly when you removed area in these places as well.

Comment: It's .Net Core, so no RouteConfig.cs and no Global.asxas.cs, just default routing in StartUp.cs

Comment: then post the code of Startup.cs for the routing which may be there under Configuration method

Comment: IIS Express is probably serving old assemblies. Find and clear the temporary file location.

Comment: It just the default routing: routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");